# Someone could help me with this exercise for beginners in neo4j,why it returns me anything?

Tags: database, neo4j, nosql

The schematic is:

[image]

The question is:Who are the friends of the friends of Claudia

My code:

```
MATCH (a:Student)-[:friend]->()-[:friend]->(b:Student) 
MATCH (a:Student)-[:friend]->()-[:friend]->(c:Pet) 
WHERE a.name= "Claudia" 
RETURN a,b,c
```

Comment: this is your clue: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/patterns/#cypher-pattern-varlength

Comment: I have not studyed the length in the querys yet,but it would be like that: ?          
 MATCH (a:Student)-[:friend]->()-[:friend]->(b:Student) 
MATCH (b:Student)-[:study*2]->(s:Subject)
WHERE a.name= "Claudias" AND s.name <> "Databases"
RETURN b

Comment: You answer is close and still long. Take  your time to study the link I gave you. Patience is a virtue. :D You can do it!